# Are there any tools that can be used to compute condition branch complexity?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

I have tried lizard and codalyze, but both can't perfectly meet my needs. For example

```
bool foo(int n) {
    if (n > 10) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool foo3(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool foo2(int n) {
    if (n > 10) {
        return foo3(n);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

output of lizard

```
================================================
  NLOC    CCN   token  PARAM  length  location
------------------------------------------------
      13      3     40      1      13 foo@1-13@exp1.cpp
       8      2     26      1       8 foo3@15-22@exp1.cpp
       8      2     27      1       8 foo2@24-31@exp1.cpp
1 file analyzed.
==============================================================
```

However, what I hope is that foo2 has the same condition branch complexity as foo. Are there any other tools I can use?